# With nested loops, in what order do the loop variables get incremented?

Tags: delphi, for-loop, matrix, position, cycle

I have a question about how are Matrices exactly filled in Delphi? In which way and which row and column first econd and which number is followed by which number in what order in Delphi? Can you help e clarify that? Details are as follows:

I have 5x5 Matrix with numbers 1 to 5 with this code:

```
for i := 1 to 5 do
   for j := 1 to 5 do
       x[i, j] := i + j;
```

What will be on position like x[2,2] and x[1,1]? What is the order of filling the matrix? In which way? What row and column is filled first, second, third etc? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: `A: array [M, N] of T => A: array [M] of array [N] of T => A: array [M*N] of T`. Verbally: 1st column, then 2nd column, etc

Comment: In case you are wondering how it is stored in memory: Delphi uses Row-Major-Order. Very few platforms (FORTRAN is one) use Column-Major-Order. Differences are explained here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Row-major_order

Comment: @Jeroen Whilst row major is prevelant now in programming environments, the overwhelming majority of executing numerical code is col major

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Curious, as I don't understand what you mean: what's the difference between "programming environments" and "executing numerical code"? Isn't that programmed in a programming environment too? When I did FORTRAN 30 years ago, I always wondered why FORTRAN was doing Column-Major-Order as most of my programming problems were row-oriented.

Comment: @Jeroen C and Pascal derived languages, there are many, are row major. For col major you have Fortran, Matlab and then extreme minorities. So more platforms/environments are row major. But way more numerical code is col major because most numerical code is still fortran or fortran derived.

Comment: @Jeroen I've never encountered a problem that is inherently row-oriented. It's always an arbitrary choice. If you think it's row oriented, just transpose it. Now it's col oriented. However, the choice, whilst arbitrary, does influence algo design. Because you always want efficient memory access patterns which are generally sequential, or as close to that as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code works from top to bottom in the order it appears.  If it helps to see it a little better (I wouldn't recommend you code like this, but just shows the logic a bit better):

```
for i := 1 to 5 do
  begin
    for j := 1 to 5 do
      begin
        x[i, j] := i + j;
      end;
  end;
```

The logic starts from i = 1 and then counts the inner loop.  So basically, you're doing this:

```
 x[1, 1] := 1 + 1;
 x[1, 2] := 1 + 2;
 ...
 x[1, 5] := 1 + 5;
 x[2, 1] := 2 + 1;
 ..
 x[5, 4] := 5 + 4;
 x[5, 5] := 5 + 5;
```

Hopefully this helps you understand how for loops work in this case.

Comment: So Matrix is filled like x[1, 1], x[1, 2] so by one row from begining to end then second row from begining to the end etc? The command x[i, j] := i + j; is done like 25 times?

Comment: @Byakugan - correct but this has little to do with matrices per se but more with nesting for loops. fyi: using two for loops to fill a matrix, its best *(performance wise)* to fill row by row *(as you are doing)*. Filling row by row, you have the advantage of memory being aligned. Filling column by column would have a lot of cache misses and a much worse performance.

Comment: How would look the filling code which fills column by column?

Comment: @Byakugan, make the outer loop iterate with j index and inner loop with i index.

Comment: @LURD, or `x` and `y`. With Cartesian coordinates it's better to imagine what's iterated.

Comment: If you want to see how this sort of thing works then you can always use debugging with watches and evaluate/modify options. You can even write a separate procedure to write the current matrix into a text file or on-screen memo if these are too limiting for what you're trying to see. This is quite a simple case, but will provide good experience of using the debugger for when you're looking at more complicated systems.

Answer (score 5):

The question has nothing to do with matrices nor Delphi per se. Instead it is all about nested for loops.

I'm going to show you how you could have worked this out for yourself. Create this simple console app:

```
program NestedLoops;

procedure Main;
var
  i, j: Integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to 5 do
    for j := 1 to 5 do
    begin
      Write('i=');
      Write(i);
      Write(' j=');
      Write(j);
      Writeln;
    end;
end;

begin
  Main;
end.
```

And you'll see output like this:

```
i=1 j=1
i=1 j=2
i=1 j=3
i=1 j=4
i=1 j=5
i=2 j=1
i=2 j=2
....
```

It's easy enough to predict this too without running code. Think about it:

- The i loop is the outer loop. On its first iteration, i is 1.
- Then the inner loop runs, and runs to completion. So we then have j values of 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5, all the while we are still at i=1, the first outer loop iteration.
- Then we have the second outer loop iteration, i=2, and a whole new complete set of inner loop j values.
- And so on for the remaining outer loop i iterations.